# Data virtualization with SQL Server DB using Marklogic

Tags: virtualization, marklogic

I would like to use data from a SQL Server database in Marklogic without moving it physically. I have read about data virtualization in Marklogic but cannot get any example or documentation explaining how to go about it. Please point me to any reference that may help me.

I have already tried reading data using MLSAM. Is this the only way and is this virtualization?

Comment: Can a Marklogic View be created on virtual data or does the data have to be stored physically in a document in the repository

Answer (score 1):

MarkLogic introduced the concept of Views to allow data visualization tools to connect to MarkLogic through ODBC, executing SQL against MarkLogic. These views are fed from XML content within MarkLogic through range indexes. So, I think that is the other way around for what you are looking for. In general, MarkLogic will need data inside its own databases, to allow indexing it.

MLSAM can be a way to pull such data in, executing SQL statements from within XQuery against external sources (contrary to xdmp:sql, which runs against the Views inside MarkLogic). Tools like RecordLoader, XQsync, and XMLSh might be worth looking at as well. See

http://developer.marklogic.com/code

HTH!

Comment: Can this (MLSAM approach) be considered as Data Virtualization. I was under the impression that Data virtualization would involve creating views on external data and querying them joining multiple such views from disparate data sources. (like in composite)

Comment: If you would use MarkLogic as a kind of proxy to access the external data, then yes, that could be seen as a way to virtualize your data. But I wouldn't recommend it. You won't benefit from any of MarkLogics index and search facilities, and you will have to do all the proxying yourself. If you want to make good use of the data within MarkLogic, then pull it in..

Comment: I completely agree with you that its best to move data into Marklogic. But i am trying to prove a technology feature that is being projected by marklogic, that it supports Data Virtualization. The problem is I just cant get a handle on how to do it technically. There seems to be absolutely no references to it. Can it be that this feature is not available in the trial version of ML 7 that i am using?